# How to remove "» (title of post or page)"?

Tags: posts, title

Whenever I put a name on a post or page, it will show up in the corner of the website as such: "» (post / page title)". When I checked the code, it looks like this:

```
<body>
"» (title

" == $0

(...)
```

How do I remove it?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an SEO Plugin installed? Have you checked it's settings?

Comment: Search your theme files for `wp_title` and/or `<title>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your code for `»` and narrow down where it's referenced. Chances are not many places. Look in all your theme and plugin folders. Even do a `grep` on the `/wp-content` folder.

`grep -winr ./wp-content -e '»'`

It looks like bad php code -- maybe `copy/paste` where the quotes didn't match up.